# Openpyxl hangs on save of large file

Tags: python, python-2.7, openpyxl

I have a script I wrote that reads an XML file and outputs relevant data to a TSV file.  I'm converting it to write a XLSX file with openpyxl.  Whenever I save my workbook at the end of the script, it hangs for 30+ seconds while saving.  I'm assuming this is due to the large amount of data I am writing ( 10144 rows to column 'BG' ).  Is there any way to optimize this so that the save is faster, or to write directly to the file while I'm generating it so it doesn't have to save like this at the end?

Comment: I took alecxe's advice and switched to `xlsxwriter`.  Much better than `openpyxl`.  Just putting this here so it's easier for future people to spot the solution without having to read through the comments below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to say what exactly is your problem, but the first thing you should try is to use [openpyxl optimized writer](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/optimized.html#optimized-writer):

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook(optimized_write = True)

ws = wb.create_sheet()

# now we'll fill it with 10k rows x 200 columns
for irow in xrange(10000):
    ws.append(['%d' % i for i in xrange(200)])

wb.save('new_big_file.xlsx') # don't forget to save!
```

Also, consider switching to [xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest) in `constant_memory` mode (see [docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/working_with_memory.html)).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Wow, `optimized_write` actually cut that down to about 3 seconds to save.  I'll look into xlsxwriter too.  Are there any other benefits to xlsxwriter over openpyxl that would warrant a switch?

Comment: Scratch that.  The resulting XLSX file is only 6kb and is empty.

Comment: Long story short, `xlsxwriter` has more control and features. No sure about the speed though.

Comment: Make sure you use only `append` method when using optimized openpyxl writer.

Comment: Oh, I'm not sure if that'll work.  My script is currently writing to specific cells as I loop through the data. I'll look into xlsxwriter and see if that can do this.

Comment: Ok, feel free to post the code you are using for openpyxl optimized writer.

Comment: Looks like openpyxl won't be able to do it after all. I'm applying style/formatting to my cells, which apparently is not supported with optimized_writer. Looks like I'll be jumping over to xlsxwriter then.

Comment: Exactly, optimized writer cannot handle style and formatting. It's for simple and fast data writing only.

Comment: Alright, switched everything over to xlsxwriter and it works great.  Supports all the formatting and it's only taking about 6 seconds to save, which is totally acceptable.

Comment: with `optimized_write = True`  get `IndexError: list index out of range`

Can you people help me??

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27640104/how-to-use-opitmized-write-in-openpyxl